# MongoDB complex update

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB 3.2 with the following document structure:

```
_id: OjbectId(),
record: [
  {
  client_id: 1002,
  shoping_list: [
    {
      list_name: "Just created",
      create_date: ISODate("2016-07-16T01:23:11.232Z"),
      items:[
        {
          id: 219213,
          amount: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  }
]
```

What I want to accomplish two tasks:

1. insert an item element into `items` field of the n-th `shoping_list` element.
2. update the i-th `items` element of the j-th `shoping_list` element.

How can I accomplish the two tasks using MongoDB shell or Spring Data MongoDB.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the mongoshell, assuming the collections is called 'lists'

1.

```
> var list = db.lists.findOne()
> list.record[0].shoping_list[n].items.push(new_item)
> db.lists.save(list)
```

2.

```
> var list = db.lists.findOne()
> list.record[0].shoping_list[j].items[i] = updated_item
> db.lists.save(list)
```